# Trouble installing Ruby +tk on Mavericks?

Tags: ruby, macports, tk-toolkit, osx-mavericks

Any idea why this isn't working on OSX 10.9?

```
sudo port install ruby19 +mactk
```

The above installs fine.

Then, when trying to run a Ruby script, foot.rb as an example, with `tk` required/used:

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- tk (LoadError)
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/craign/bin/foot.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Mavericks just came out. Developers are still wading through issues, so these sort of problems will crop up. It's the price we pay when we walk the bleeding-edge. Your best solution is to take it to the developers for MacPorts and help them by providing your information and pertinent log output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem, and it was fixed by removing my ActiveState 8.6 installation.  This left tcl8.5.9 as the default, which seems to work fine.